# introduction appropriate library for converting sound to the word

Tags: opencv, voice-recognition

I'm new at Artificial Intelligence
And now I'm searching for a good library as powerful as Open Cv 
To convert sound to word ,
Please recommend me , thanks for help .

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

CMU has an open source "speech recognition toolkit" library called Sphinx, which has support for a lot of speech recognition algorithms. It has various versions, suitable for even embedded platforms.

Sphinx:  http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Python interface for Sphinx: https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python